# First Letter only Is Updated on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to merge two orders on my application ... I've declared two variables to update them ... For example the order has a waiter(John) and a table number (21) ... I want to update second order with the same waiter and table .. So i get waiter as (J) and table as (2)

this is my query

```
declare  @orderOne float = 4429 ; 
declare  @orderTwo float = 4893 ; 
declare  @tableNumber varchar = (SELECT  TOP 1 tableNumber FROM ORDERS WHERE orderId in (@orderOne,@orderTwo) AND isActive = 0);
declare  @waiterN varchar = (SELECT  TOP 1 waiterName FROM ORDERS WHERE orderId in (@orderOne,@orderTwo) AND isActive = 0);

UPDATE orders SET orderId =  @orderOne , tableNumber = @tableNumber , waiterName = @waiterN  where orderId = @orderTwo ;
```

Comment: define the length of `varchar(99)` if you not define then it will assume 1, thats why you are getting `J` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare  @orderOne float = 4429 ; 
declare  @orderTwo float = 4893 ; 
declare  @tableNumber varchar(100);   --<-- define variable length, default is 1
declare  @waiterN varchar(100);       --<-- define variable length, default is 1 

SELECT  TOP 1 @tableNumber = tableNumber 
             ,@waiterN  = waiterName
FROM ORDERS WHERE orderId in (@orderOne,@orderTwo) AND isActive = 0;



UPDATE orders 
  SET orderId =  @orderOne 
    , tableNumber = @tableNumber 
    , waiterName = @waiterN  
where orderId = @orderTwo ;
```